# How can I include a PNG image using XeTeX?

Tags: graphics, xetex, png

I can include a pdf image using `pdflatex` as a compiler, and the code:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

....

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{chiaroscuro-victorian.png}
\end{figure}
```

But when I compile using XeTeX, I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in chiaroscuro-victorian.png (no BoundingBox).
```

I'm also using the `mla` package, if that's relevant at all:

```
\usepackage{mla}
```

How can I import this image and use XeTeX?

Comment: As a sanity check: substitute `example-image-a.png` for your image to check it works. If so, the problem is presumably as it appears and you can probably just tell LaTeX the bounding box explicitly. See the `graphicx` manual for the required syntax.

Comment: You need to use `\usepackage[dvips,xetex]{graphicx}` before loading `mla`, which (wrongly I think) tests for `pdftex`, but not the other engines.  This leads to loading `graphicx` with the `dvips` driver, which clashes with your desire to use XeTeX on the backend.

Comment: ... However, *inside* the `.sty` file, which is where the documentation (such as it is) can be found, it states the package is "For use with LaTeX and pdflatex."  So: *caveat utens*!

Comment: Actually, I'd advise against using the package altogether: it uses outdated packages (e.g, `times`), doesn't use tried and true packages where it could (e.g., `geometry`, `csquotes`, `setspace`), and encourages ad hoc formatting (e.g., using its `\tab` macro to indent following `\section`-related commands).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work with XeTeX (i.e., using the `xelatex` command):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips,xetex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifpdf,mla}% <-- mla.sty requires ifpdf.sty, but (perversely) doesn't load it
%\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{chiaroscuro-victorian.png}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The problem is due to `mla.sty` (which I'd avoid using).  It has the following definition:

```
% New code thanks to Edward Z. Yang
\ifpdf % We're generating a pdf
    \usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}    
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth      
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight          
    \usepackage{thumbpdf}    
    %\pdfcompresslevel=9       
\else     
    \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} 
\fi
```

In essence, if you aren't using pdfTeX as the engine, it loads `graphicx` with a specific driver, causing the conflict.  Loading `graphicx` first with the `xetex` option solves the clash (you also need to load `dvips` so your loading of the package doesn't cause a clash with what `mla.sty` does.

Comment: Great! But now the images are indented a half-inch, like new paragraphs are. How can I fix that?

Comment: Actually, can you explain what you mean by editing your question so it shows the problem?  I'd have to make a lot of assumptions about what you're doing otherwise.... (Please strive to make it a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528).)

Answer (score -1):

A PNG image is a raster image, which has no physical dimensions. If you image is 100 pixels by 100 pixels, you can print that out in thumbnail size or as a full page. Since XeTeX is putting the picture on a page, it needs to know how large to make it, e.g.,

```
\includegraphics[width=3in]{chiaroscuro-victorian.png}
```

You don't need to specify the width and the height because TeX can calculate it, since it knows the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: This will not solve the problem in this case, which arises due to `mla.sty`'s less-than-ideal implementation.  (Also: `scale=0.6` is usually a fine way to specify size for .png graphic inclusions.)

Comment: I'm curious how large a 100 x 100 image (for instance) appears?

Comment: The question here is why the `\includegraphics` command fails, not about how to specify a specific size.  `scale=X` works in general; but neither it nor `width=Y` will fix the problem of the OP without fixing the driver clash caused by using XeTeX with the `mla.sty` package.